# Checking the structure is existing or not

Tags: coldfusion

Here is my array loop which has structures inside that

I am looping over it and i need to skip those fields where the struct is not defined, howver i am getting everytime

Here is my code:

```
<cfloop index="apos" from=1 to="#arrayLen(myarray)#">
<cfdump var="#myarray[apos].company#">
    <cfdump var="#StructKeyExists(myarray[apos].company,'#myarray[apos].company.size#')#">
    <cfdump var="#StructFindKey(myarray[apos].company,'myarray[apos].company.size','ALL')#">
</cfloop>
```

The error is throwing on line 3, where i am getting error: **Element COMPANY.SIZE is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.**

Although i had tried the structFindvalue, but that does not work, perhaps that is expecting some simple values, so what could be the best possible alternative here

Comment: If you are looping through your array, you may find it useful to see if each element actually is a structure.  The isStruct() function is available for that.  Mind you, if your array is built in such a way that all elements are guaranteed to be structures, that won't be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `structKeyExists` you want to give that function the struture to look and the key you're looking for, so in `myarray[apos].company` you want to see if 'size' exists, not the entire structure.

```
<cfloop index="apos" from=1 to="#arrayLen(myarray)#">
  <cfdump var="#myarray[apos].company#">
  <cfdump var="#StructKeyExists(myarray[apos].company,'size')#">
</cfloop>
```